# Broadcast join in Pyspark got OnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, python, pyspark

I use broadcast join in pyspark on a not very large dataframe, but got oom error. Code is very easy as follow:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
df1 = sc.read.parquet("xxx")
df2 = sc.read.parquet("xxx")
df = df1.join(broadcast(df2), on=["key"])
```

after some seconds i got OOM error

```
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 26024"...
```

df2 is not very larget, 1868895 lines. The hdfs file is about 142M. I can easily load all data in driver code and use it as a UDF there is no problem. But when using broadcast join, the OOM appear.

My configuration is as follow:

```
spark.python.worker.memory=2048m
spark.executor.memory=8g
spark.driver.memory=7g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase value of spark.sql.broadcastTimeout parameter,

Where spark is SparkSession object

Answer (score 0):

Parquet file will get explode while processing. Due to high compression ratio it will reach more than your configured memory. Out of 8GB memory you will get 60% i.e. around 4gb for processing. Try to increase memory or increase broadcast join memory.